# Anchor tag <a> is set to inline but still taking up all the space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in my html but the `<a> tag` is acting like a block display even though I set the css to `display:inline;`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="card card-body bg-light">
    <div class="text-right">
      <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Add Review</a>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <p> <strong>John </strong>- a tag is inline but it's still taking up the space</p>
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" href="#"> Edit Review </a>
    <form id="delete_button" action="routeToDelete" method="POST">
      <input class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete" >
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
I set the `id="delete_button"` to `display:inline` but it doesn't become inline with the `a tag` . I noticed that the `a tag` is taking the space so that must be the problem. but then I tried inspecting the `a tag` and found that the content is taking up all the block(1042x24) in developer tools so I also tried making it `display:inline` too but nothing happens.

The result should be that the **EDIT REVIEW** and **DELETE** BUTTON should be on the same line. EDIT REVIEW button should be the same size as the DELETE button

Comment: share full code including bootstrap and the CSS you added ... it's a probably a simple cache issue

Comment: The delete button is a different element than the full-size edit review button btw.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code you posted so something else must be causing that. More info needed!

Comment: Try to inspect the element with your browser's developer tools and you will probably find out what's happening.

Comment: Most likely set to 100% width

Comment: If it's `inline-block` (not `inline`) and set to 100% width, it will act like a block level element

Answer (score 3):

Somehow you are setting the width of the 'Edit Review' button to 100% (i.e. `width:100%;`). It is difficult to know how this bit of CSS styling is being applied without getting access to your full code.

Culprits could be:

- `.btn-warning` - this is the most likely culprit, as it is only applied to the 'Edit Review' button in your example code.
- `a`, `.btn`, `.btn-xs` - these are less likely as they are used elsewhere in the same example, without their width appearing to be 100%.

Let me know if that helps you work it out.

---

## Demo

I've added some CSS styling to mimic your issue, and applied it to the most likely culprit `.btn-warning`, then demonstrated how it can be fixed (either remove that line of styling or override it with another class).

```css
.btn-warning {
  width: 100%;
}

.problem-fix {
  width: auto;
}

#delete_button {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card card-body bg-light">

  <h4>Current Issue</h4>
  
  <a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" href="#"> Edit Review </a>
  
  <form id="delete_button" action="routeToDelete" method="POST">
    <input class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
  </form>

</div>

<hr>

<div class="card card-body bg-light">

  <h4>Demonstration of Solution</h4>
  
  <a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning problem-fix" href="#"> Edit Review </a>
  
  <form id="delete_button" action="routeToDelete" method="POST">
    <input class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
  </form>

</div>
```